# Use same color for multiple using statements in "plot for" loop

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following loop in my gnuplot script to iterate over multiple files and draw one graph:

```
files = system("echo $(ls *.csv)")
plot for [f in files] f  using 0:2:xtic(1) with lp ,\
for [f in files] f using 0:2:2 with labels font ',8' offset 1,0.5 notitle "",\
for [f in files] f  using 0:2:3 with yerrorbars title ""
```

For every datapoint a linepoint, a label and a yerrorbar is drawn.

Is it possible to use the same color for corresponding linepoint, yerrorbar and label?
If yes, how?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set linetype cycle ...` to define after how many iterations the same patterns and colors are repeated:

```
files = system("echo $(ls *.csv)")

set linetype cycle words(files)

plot for [f in files] f  using 0:2:xtic(1) with lp ,\
     for [f in files] f using 0:2:2 with labels font ',8' offset 1,0.5 notitle "",\
     for [f in files] f  using 0:2:3 with yerrorbars title ""
```

Here is a simple example:

```
set linetype cycle 2
set samples 10
set key left
set style function linespoints
plot x, 2*x, 3*x, 4*x, 5*x, 6*x
```

The output with 4.6.5 is:

[image]